# Wait that input value is setted with toDataURL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jcrop, todataurl

I try to upload an image from a canvas with Jcrop.
I set the value of the canvas inside a hidden input.
When I submit the form the value is not setted yet.

```
$("#formEtatCivil").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").attr('name') === 'Update') {
        if (canvas) {
            var head = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,';
            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
            if (Math.round((dataUrl.length - head.length)*3/4) > 5000000) {
                alert('La photo doit faire moins de 5Mo');
                return false;
            }
            $('#prs_photo_reel').val(dataUrl);
        }
    }
    if ($(this).validationEngine('validate')) {
        $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="' + $("input[type=submit][clicked=true]").attr('name') + '" value="1">');
        $(this).unbind().submit();
    }
});
```

When I try `if (!empty($_POST['prs_photo_reel']))` on the server side, it returns false

My form contain:

```
<input type="hidden" name="prs_photo_reel" id="prs_photo_reel">
```

It work on another server with the same files on it

Comment: The input is in your form tag ? The attribute 'name', of your input, is 'prs_photo_reel' ?

Comment: @R3tep yes everything is ok. It work in my pre-production server but it's too slow for the production idk why

Comment: What is the value of canvas in case of your production server?

Comment: @R3tep I already tried but it's the same behavior.

Comment: @LajosArpad What do you mean ? The canvas contain the picture the user try to upload using jcrop

Comment: @Splinteer I mean you have a variable called canvas and you check whether it is truey if (canvas) { The question is what is the value of this variable?

Comment: @LajosArpad it's $("#canvas")[0], but there is no problem getting the value of the dataurl. But when I submit, the value is not submitted yet